# CSRF Token not verified with actual gateway in Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, payment-methods

My payment page form works just fine with the dummy gateway, but once I change it to use my authorize.net gateway it says that the CSRF token isn't verified. The code below isn't complete, but I figured maybe there is something in this part that is causing it? Any ideas would be great, thanks!

```
<form class="flex-container flex-center flex-col nav-buttons flex-lg" method="POST">
  {{ getCsrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/payments/pay"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/store/customer/order?number={number}"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="cancelUrl" value="/store/checkout/payment"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="paymentMethodId" value="1"/>

{% set formValues = {
    firstName: paymentForm is defined ? paymentForm.firstName : (cart.billingAddress ? cart.billingAddress.firstName : ''),
    lastName: paymentForm is defined ? paymentForm.lastName : (cart.billingAddress ? cart.billingAddress.lastName : ''),
    number: paymentForm is defined ? paymentForm.number : '',
    cvv: paymentForm is defined ? paymentForm.cvv : '',
    month: paymentForm is defined ? paymentForm.month : 1,
    year: paymentForm is defined ? paymentForm.year : (currentYear +1),
} %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welp... I feel like an idiot. It wouldn't let it through because I didn't set the endpoints found at https://craftcommerce.com/docs/payment-gateways